# Transport equation - PDE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have to solve explicity:

$au_{t}+bDu +cu=0 $ if $(x, t) \in R^{n} \times ]0, infty[ $ and $u=f$ if $(x, t) \in R^{n} \times {0}$

Well anyone has any idea? I tried but i got nowhere.

Comment: Do you mean $bDu_x$?

Comment: @Paul no, Du is the gradiente. So Du$=(u_{x_{1}}, ..., u_{x_{n}})$

Comment: Sorry yes, n dimensional.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve first order linear partial differential equations using the [method of characteristics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_characteristics). I advise you to try it out and see how far you get. If you get stuck at any point, share your attempts, and maybe someone can assist you based on your work.